# Magento 1.8.1 Can't login admin

Tags: authentication, magento-1.8

Clean install Magento 1.8.1. (2 hours old) I experienced the Magneto application booted off two separate users simultaneously on two separate Chrome Browsers(PCs) once I enter the Paypal tab to set up a new configuration on a clean install of 1.8.1. Do not remember if I  got to save any Paypal edits.  I had been in the back end editing for than 2 hours.  I set the session time out at 36000 early on in the setup. Now it appears to give me as session id but will not allow access to the back end.  It just keeps showing the login form after providing the correct credentials. Nothing in logs, cookies were wiped, cache cleared, even tried FF and observed the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following code in /app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

and put this line below the ablove code :

getFormKey(); ?>" />

Comment: http://mukeshbagri.blogspot.in/2014/04/magento-issue-in-magento-after-upgrade.html